# MVC 4 return entries from database excluding specific items

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I've been changing this call around for some time  and can not quite get it to work. I am trying to return some records from a database and exclude items based on their ID numbers.

This is a database of quotes and when someone hides a quote it stores the quoteID in a cookie (required) and when returning to the site, The cookie.value is read.

I need to filter these IDs out of the return query and display the results in a view using WebGrid. I have the cookie part working. I retrieve the values (could be multiple) and split this into a list of strings. I then run a foreach loop ans parse the string to an integer and then try to remove quotes that I have retrieved from the database. Here is the code as I am using it...

```
// Filter on Cookie Value using tokenizer
string value = Request.Cookies.Get("hideCookie").Value;
List<string> values = value.Split(' ').ToList();
var quotes2 = db.Quotes.Include(q => q.QName);

foreach (var i in values)
{
    int idv = int.Parse(i);
    quotes2 = from q in quotes2 where q.QuoteID != idv select q;
}
return View(quotes2.ToList());
```

This throws an error "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Exercise4.Models.Quote' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'QName'." (QName being an entry in the database record).

If I remove the ToList() in the return View(), quotes2 gets passed to the View but throws this error on the webGrid "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Exercise4.Models.Quote' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'QName'."

I'm sure there is a much better way of doing this. Can you please point me in the correct direction so I can stop banging my head against my desk...

Comment: Can you show us your Quote class. It seems theres an issue with your mapping,

Comment: I changed the call  from db.Quotes.Include(q => q.Qname) to db.Quotes.Include(q => q.QuoteID) which seem to rectify the problem.